# People half-standing for אלקינו in zimun

Tags: minhag, bentching, meal-seudah, standing-sitting, zimun

When conducting a *zimun* with ten or more men, the nusach is to say "...ברוך **אלקינו** שאכלנו משלו".

I have noticed that many people, when saying the word "אלקינו", get up from their seats at least a little bit, similar to the respectful gesture many people do when the *rav* gets up to speak.

What is the reason (if there is one at all) for this practice, and what is its source?

Comment: My Rov says one should not half-stand but remain sitting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is said in name of Rav Chaim Soloveitchik that when we say Elokenu it makes the Zimun into a Davar Shebikedusha. That is the reason why some people stand when they say Elokenu, since according to some the Minhag is to stand during a Davar Shebikedusha. This Minhag is not universal. Sefardim do not stand by Kaddish in many cases.

Comment: What constitutes a *davar shebikedusha*?

Comment: I guess something that is done with a Tzibbur and includes the name of Hashem, although I do not have a source for this.

Comment: What about all the parts of *tefilla* that we sit down for? Particularly *birchos k'rias shema* and *uva l'tzion* which both have "kedusha" in them.

Comment: You are saying Birchas Kriyas Shema by yourself. You are not answering Amen to it. As I told you I have no source as to what constitutes a davar shebikedusha.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7761

Comment: Do you have a source for this Reb Chaim? After learning the sugya it seems to me (and several achronim) that the opposite is true; bentching is never a davar shebikdusha

Answer (score 2):

I heard once that the reason to half-stand is to satisfy all two opinions on the matter: those who hold it is appropriate to stand and those who don't.

Comment: Kind of like putting up the mezuza diagonal.

Comment: Just be careful of ending up satisfying neither! (@jake and @WAF)

Comment: Are there those who hold one must sit?

Comment: I saw the Ben Ish Chai (sorry forgot the exact source) who made fun of those who do a little hop for barchu instead of standing up fully and bowing. He said it's better to simply bow your head if you're not going to bother standing. I assume the same would be true if one must stand for zimmun. (@DoubleAA @jake)