# What is the meaning of Davar Shebakedusha?

Tags: words

How does something become a Davar Shebakedusha? What is the criteria?

This question was inspired by the discussion over here. [People half-standing for אלקינו in zimun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7748/people-half-standing-for-in-zimun)

Comment: Relevant hearsay from R' Chaim Soloveitchik: http://elomdus.blogspot.com/2007/12/zimun-of-10-people.html

Comment: There are different types of 'devarim shebikdusha' (see Gittin 59b, for example), so I assume that you're only asking here about things that, due to their 'kedusha', require a minyan of ten Jewish men

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps someone can answer directly. Otherwise, this might help: Gather a list of things that are and a list of things that are not *d'varim shebikdusha* and see whether a rule can be figured out from the examples. I'm marking this answer "community wiki" so additions to it will be easier.

#### *D'varim shebikdusha*:

- *kadish* (*MB* 55:2, from *Mgila* 23:2)
- *k'dusha* (ditto)
- *bar'chu* (ditto)
- Torah-reading (ditto)
- *n'si'as kapayim* of the *kohanim* (ditto)
- *chazaras hashatz* (N.B.: *MB* 55:5 says it's considered such because it has *k'dusha* in it.)

#### Not:

- Anything that we know does not require a *minyan*. (This is because any *davar shebikdusha* ipso facto requires a *minyan*.)

#### Halachic Dispute:

- *shlosh `esrei middot* (the 13 Divine attributes): The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 565:5) says that they are *d'varim shebikdusha*.  The source is the Rashba (Responsa 1:211), but in the printed editions, he says that they are **like** *d'varim shebikdusha*.  The Tur says that they are not.

Comment: Anyone have the book מועדי הרב (by שלמה זאב פיק, published ca. 2003)? Pages 55–56 supposedly have some information on this.

Comment: Note that there are things which require 10 men but is still not a davar shebikdusha (see Aruch Hashulchan Even Ha'Ezer 62:11)