# wording of the invitation to birkas hamazon

Tags: minhag, words, ashkenazi, bentching, zimun

I know some *Ashk'nazim* say *rabosay n'varech*, some *rabosay mir velen bentschen*, and some *hertzi rabosay mir velen bentschen*. (Any other forms?) Is there any particular reason given for one or another?

Comment: Sephardim say hav lan nvarech to start it off.

Comment: @soandos I think Syrians, at least, say _hav lan v'nivrich_, but I was asking about _Ashk'nazim_.

Comment: Apologies, don't see how that is present in the question.

Comment: The Yemenites say the single word, "N'varekh".

Comment: I have a friend who goads people into saying anything along the lines of "maybe it's time we bentch" and then jumps into "Yehi Shem..."

Comment: Very similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77529

Comment: The reason we say the invitation is to tell people we're ready to bentch. It just so happens that some say it in Yiddish/Hebrew, but you could theoretically say anything along the lines of "let's bentch now."

Answer (score 9):

See the excellent article [here](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2007/12/proper-nusach-for-zimmun.html) regarding the proper nussach of zimmun.

The highlights are: that the introductory bit (everything before Nevarech she'achalnu mishelo) is based on a ruling of the Zohar quoted in the Magen Avraham quoted in the Mishna Berura ([OC 192 sk 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=187)) and in the Aruch HaShulchan ([OC 192:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A7.D7.A6.D7.91_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91)) which says that every "[davar shebikusha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7761/759)" needs a oral preparation, we introduce the zimmun with an introductory call to join together. The phrase the Zohar mentions (as quoted in the Be'er Heitiv [OC 192 sk 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=187)) is Hav Lan VeNivrich which is an allusion to the Talmud [Pesachim 103a-b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=103&format=pdf) where the phrase is used to let people know that bentching was soon, NOT as part of the zimmun (as evidenced by the parallel phrase in the gemara: Hav Lan VeNishteh). The Be'er Heitiv and Mishna Berura there and the Aruch Hashulchan there all point out that the custom is to say the initial bit in the vernacular, hence: rabosai mir vellen bentchin. Those who say hav lan venivrich are using the Zohar/Gemara's original wording. Everyone else is using their own vernacular or some original combination/formulation of honorifics and blessing-verbs, as all we are looking for is an oral preparation. I have even see it done to "Ok Guys, Let's Bentch!"