# May one say Oseh Shalom at any time?

Tags: halacha, tefilla

Are there restrictions pertaining to the recitation of the Oseh Shalom prayer? May it only be said with Kaddish?

Comment: Or Shemona Esre of course.

Comment: I wonder if it has an independent existence from *Kaddish*, a [*davar shebikdusha*](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7761/2), in that it is Hebrew, unlike the rest of *Kaddish*, which is Aramaic, and in that it's also found at the end of the [*Amida*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidah), as @HachamGabriel notes. I wonder what its source is. ...

Comment: @IsaacMoses [This link](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) might help you.

Comment: @WAF, [all set](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30891/2), thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this does not fully answer the question, but it was too long as a comment. It addresses an apparent underlying assumption that *Oseh Shalom* is a component of the *amida* and *kaddish*:

The *Oseh Shalom* prayer, which concludes the *amida*, *kaddish*, and *birkas hamazon*, is appended to the end of those prayers. According to [*Yoma* 53b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=53b&format=pdf), a prayer of "*shalom*" is recited after the *amida* by way of taking leave.

The specific formulation of this prayer is not found in the Talmud, but it appears in the *Siddur of Rav Amram Gaon* (9th century), as well as in the writings of several 11th century (and later) rishonim, as following all three prayers. This formulation is founded on the verse in [*Iyov* (25:2)](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2725.htm): המשל ופחד עמו עושה שלום במרומיו ("He who makes harmony in His lofty heavens").<sup>*</sup>

The *Oseh Shalom* prayer is separate prayer recited after the aforementioned prayers. In the case of *kaddish*, this is indicated by the wording of the *Shulchan Aruch* (OC 56:5): "After one concludes *kaddish*, he takes three steps backwards and afterwards says '*Oseh shalom*', etc." In this regard, the [*T'rumas HaDeshen* (§13)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14655&st=&pgnum=16) equates the *amida* with *kaddish*. Likewise, interruptions are allowed after the completion of the *amida*, even before reciting *Oseh Shalom* (see *Mishna B'rura* 122:4).

---

<sup>*</sup>  <sub>The Talmud ([Rosh HaShana 23b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=23b&format=pdf)) interprets this verse as describing the carefully separate placement of the celestial bodies. Perhaps this prayer therefore aptly fits the requirement described in Yoma (ibid.) of extending a prayer of peace towards one's left and then towards the right.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you may say it whenever you want and there are no restrictions.

Comment: If you're, say, Rabbi _Chayim_ Kanievsky, then that you know of no restriction is informative. If you're, say, me, then it's not. Since none of us know who you are, this answer really doesn't help anyone. That said, welcome to the site; I hope you stick around and find other questions to answer, preferably with sources cited in the answers.