# When have I started Shemoneh Esrei?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

There is a halacha that one is not allowed to interrupt once he has started Shemoneh Esrei until he has finished, with various exceptions (O.C. 104).

Let's say I take my three steps forward and then realize that the guy about to start davening behind me is the world's slowest davener and I [will be stuck here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19008/4794) until Moshiach comes (speedily in our days amen!) if I don't relocate.  Can I relocate at this point?

When am I considered to have started?  After I take three steps forward?  After I say Hashem sefasai?  After I say baruch of the first beracha?

Comment: Is this during *Shacharis*, or is it during another *t'filla*? Because although the *amida* essentially doesn't start until at least ה' שפתי, the need to juxtapose *g'ula* to *t'filla* could create further restrictions.

Comment: If you would be stuck there until Moshiach comes, I would advise you to stay! How long can a Shemoneh Esrei be?

Comment: @Fred juxtaposition of geula to tefila applies at Maariv as well, to a lesser extent

Comment: See Brachos 4b - Rebbi Yochanan and Rebbi Yehoshua ben Levi. I believe we hold that לכתחילה you should be סומך in מעריב as well, but to a lesser extent - and therefore if you are late you can skip to daven שמונה עשרה with the ציבור. (I think I heard this on an online dafyomi shiur.)

Comment: @Fred My question is about in all cases, but to isolate the point, let's make it about mincha.  Do you have a source that it doesn't start until ה' שפתי?

Comment: @YEZ Indeed I do (it's based on *B'rachos* 9b). There's some *reyd* in the *poskim* about the function and nature of ה' שפתי, so it may not be absolutely clear cut. Further, even if ה' שפתי is attached to the *amida* that you are saying, that doesn't necessarily mean that you can't start over and say it another time if you've already said it once; it's just a *pasuk*.

Comment: @Eliyahu True, the *Tashbetz Kattan* (§227) cites the Maharam miRothenberg that no pasuk except for ה' שפתי should be recited between *g'ula* and *t'filla* even during *Ma'ariv*: מהר"ם ז"ל אומר לעולם ה' שפתי תפתח בין בשחרית בין בערבית קודם תפלת ש"ע כיון דתקינו רבנן יתיה בתפלה כתפלה אריכתא דמיא ולא הוי הפסק. אבל אינו אומר כי שם ה' אקרא וכו' בשום פעם. כיון דלא תקינוהו רבנן הוי הפסק. ובמוסף ובמנחה אומר כי שם ה' אקרא וכו' אבל בתפלת מעריב אינו אומר דהוי הפסק אפילו לר' יוחנן דאמר תפלת ערבית רשות מ"מ כיון שהוא מתפלל מודה רבי יוחנן שמצוה לסמוך גאולה לתפלה

Comment: @Fred that would depend on if you are considered to have begun after saying the posuk.  I guess I will have to wait with bated breath for your source.

Comment: @YEZ See *nos'ei keilim* on OC 111 regarding the status of ה' שפתי as part of the *amida*. Especially see *Bi'ur Halacha* (111, s.v. *chozeir v'omeir*) that it is not an essential enough element of the *amida* that it is *m'akeiv* the *t'filla*, but it is an element of the *amida* in the sense that it does not create a *hefseik* between *g'ula* and *t'filla*. See *Divrei Chamudos* on the Rosh (first *perek* of *B'rachos*, 53) that even according to the opinions that one may answer *amein* to the *chazan* after גאל ישראל, one may not answer if one has already recited ה' שפתי...

Comment: @YEZ However, see *Rav P'alim* (4:4) that when there is no issue of סמיכת גאולה לתפילה, one may interrupt after ה' שפתי to respond to *kadish* and then repeat the *pasuk*: ואשר שאלתם על אשר כתוב בס' בן איש חי בהלכות שנה ראשונה פ' ויקהל אות יו"ד בתפלת המנחה אם התחיל פסוק ה' שפתי תפתח ועדיין לא התחיל בברכה ושמע קדיש וכו' יענה ויחזור לומר ה' שפתי תפתח וכו' ונסתפקתם אם דין זה נוהג גם בתפלת מוסף דאין שם סמיכות גאולה לתפלה או לאו.
תשובה: פשוט הוא דדין זה נוהג גם בתפלת מוסף כיון דהטעם הוא שוה כאן וכאן דבשניהם אין חשש משום סמיכות גאולה לתפלה.

Comment: @Fred All of this seems to constitute an answer.  Although I don't see how you know it doesn't start _until_ then - what about after 3 steps before I say it?

Comment: @YEZ The custom of taking three steps forward before prayer is found in *Machzor Vitry* (21): מפסיע לפניו שלש פסיעות [ו]לאחריו דכת' ורגליהם רגל ישרה הרי שלש רגלים ושלש פסיעות קודם תפלה ואחר כך ישרה... כשהוא מגיע לפניו ממהר ומפסיע שלש פסיעות ואחר כך השתחוו לו במגן אברהם וכף רגליה[ם] ככף רגל עגל הרי שלש פסיעות לאחר תפלה מל(א)כי צבאות ידודון ידודון בהליכה ידודון בחזרה וכמה ג' פרסאות בהליכה כנגד מחנה ישראל וכנגדן אנו עושין ג' פסיעות בהליכה ובחזרה. This is brought down by the Rokeach (*Hil. T'filla* 322) and mentioned in a gloss on OC 95:1. The steps simply appear to be preparation for *t'filla*...

Comment: @YEZ Incidentally, see [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30891), which discusses when the *t'filla* ends.