# How does one say kaddish if he is in the middle of amidah?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, kaddish

Pretty straight forward: How does one say kaddish if he is in the middle of amidah? A few examples of this:
If you come late; if you take a long time to say amidah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may not interrupt the *amida* to recite *kaddish* if one is in the middle of the *amida*. Rather, one should pause and silently (and attentively) listen to the person who is reciting the *kaddish* and fulfill his obligation thereby ([*Shulchan Aruch* OC 104:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96)).

After the word *yisbarach* (after *amein y'hei sh'meih rabba*), one should continue with his *amida* and not listen to the rest of the *kaddish* ([*Mishna B'rura* 104:27](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96)).

This approach should also be used for *bar'chu* and *k'dusha* (*Mishna B'rura* 104:26,28).

If one has already completed the final blessing of the *amida* (and preferably also the first *yihyu l'ratzon*), one may answer *amein y'hei sh'meih rabba*, etc., as well as *amein* to the sentence ending *da'amiran b'alma* ([*Mishna B'rura* 122:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%91)). (One may also respond to *k'dusha*, *bar'chu*, *amein* to the third and sixteenth blessings of the repetition of the *amida*, and the words *modim anachnu Lach* from the *modim d'rabbanan*).

If one has completed the final *yihyu l'ratzon* at the end of the *amida* but somehow didn't have a chance to take three steps back, he may respond *amein* to anything (*Mishna B'rura* 122:4).

Comment: I got the impression that @NS23 is referring to a mourner who is late and should _say_ kaddish, not just respond. AFAIK, the answer is that he can't interrupt the Amidah to say kaddish. If he has finished and said yiyhiu ratzon, but not yet stepped back and said Oseh shalom, there may well be grounds to permit him to say kaddish since he is in the same state as the Shat"z, and his steps back at the end of kaddish serve also for the Amidah.

Comment: @Epicentre As I wrote, "One may not interrupt the amida to recite kaddish if one is in the middle of the amida." You may very well be correct that if he finished the second *yihyu l'ratzon* but wasn't able to take three steps back that he can actually recite *kaddish*, particularly in light of the *Ma'amar Mord'chai* cited by the *Mishna B'rura* 122:4 (who permits saying ברוך הוא וברוך שמו at that point).

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30891