# Should I answer the kaddish if I'm still at the amidah?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, kaddish, amen

Generally, when I say the *amidah* with a *minyan*, I'm one of the last (if not the last) persons finishing. This means I'm still at the *amidah* when the *kaddish* is recited. And I don't know if I should keep praying, respond *amen*, or keep silent. What should I do when this happens?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/54061

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [*Shulchan Aruch*](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%93) says that one should not answer to *kaddish* or *kedusha* in the middle of *amidah*. He says that one should stop praying, listen and *lechaven* and that will be as though one answered.

In [*Pninei Halacha*](http://ph.yhb.org.il/02-17-15/) Rabbi Eliezer Melamed brings sources that some say that doing so would constitute a *hefsek*. His conclusion is that one should wait and listen, as the *Shulchan Aruch* says, unless it intereferes with one's *kavana*, in which case it is allowed to go by those who say that it is forbidden to stop.

Comment: Thanks! But who says it is forbidden to stop?

Comment: @Gabe12 No problem, it is there in the notes: Rabeinu Tam and the Rif say one is not allowed to stop. Rashi and Rabeinu Chananel say one must stop and listen. The Tosfot and the Ran say the *minhag* is to stop and listen, and that's what the *Shulchan Aruch* decided. But if it intereferes with *kavana* Rabbi Melamed says that one can go with the above, as stated as well in Tzitz Eliezer (11, 3) and Halichot Shelomo (6, 12).

Comment: I don't have it before me now but seem to recall that some _acharonim_ explain that the stop-and-listen rule applies only to "_Y'he sh'meh..._".

Comment: @msh210 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/54061