# Reason for "Oseh Shalom" in 3 places

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, kaddish, bentching, shalom-peace

The phrase starting with the words  עושה שלום במרומיו ("He who makes peace in his high places") is said in 3 places and always at the end (or very near it):

- *Birkat Hamazon*
- *Kaddish*
- *Shmoneh Esreh*

What is the origin of this phrase and why are these 3 items considered important to share the same phrase? Is there any relationship / commonality of these items that warrants a concluding phrase dealing with the theme of peace?

Comment: I have a siddur based off the mishneh torah, and it does not appear after the qaddish and the birkath hamazon. If I recall correctly, it does not appear at all in the siddur of saadia gaon, but I don't have it on me.

Comment: [_Sha"s_ also ends with peace.](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%92_%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93#.D7.9E.D7.A9.D7.A0.D7.94_.D7.99.D7.91) I have always suspected this was a theme.

Comment: Partial answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30891. (Aside from the verse mentioned there, see [*Y'sha'yahu* 27:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1027.htm#5), *T'hillim* [125:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26c5.htm#5) and [128:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26c8.htm#6), which may have inspired the phrasing in the remainder of the prayer).

Comment: See the begining of medrash rabba on parshas Pinchas.

Comment: @Ploni I don't see it as a dupe of that question. The other one is specific to the Amidah.

Comment: @DanF "Why is this prayer here? **It seems to end other prayers as well such as kaddish and the harachamans following bentching.** Is there a common thread?" How is that not a dupe? (Emphasis mine) but this can't be closed as a dupe, because that also has no answer.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Indeed, it does look like a dupe, as he's asking the same thing. I may have to place a bounty on that one. If for no other reason so that we can get an answer there, and that I can close this one! Weird policy, in a way, no? Thanks for noticing this.

Comment: @DanF I just spent an hour researching it, and posted an answer there, so I'll welcome a bounty... Yes, the policy is very strange.  I think the answer there adequately solves your problems, although there is no certain correct answer.