# Custom of standing when a tzaddik passes by

Tags: minhag, standing-sitting, bowing-kneeling, tzaddikim, yahrtzeit

I am asking this question in light of a situation I witnessed recently:

When the senior rabbi of our shul--a very righteous man who was keeping his wife's yahrzeit that night--walked past the audience to come to the stage, a few people seated on the end of the front row nearest him stood halfway up, or possibly stood up and bowed.

What were they doing and what are the details of this custom? Who, what, when, and where do we do it?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7748/people-half-standing-for-%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95-in-zimun?lq=1

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35429/kissing-a-sefer-torah-as-it-passes/59344#59344

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Leviticus 19:32](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0319.htm#32)

> מִפְּנֵי שֵׂיבָה תָּקוּם, וְהָדַרְתָּ פְּנֵי זָקֵן
>   Thou shalt rise up before the hoary head, and honour the face of the old man

The Talmud (Kiddushin 32b) understands this to refer (in addition to the elderly) to any Torah scholar, and so it is codified in Shulchan Arukh (YD 244:1) that one must stand to honor a Torah scholar who passes within 4 cubits of him.

This is likely what the people you witnessed were doing.

Comment: I have also heard that the word זקן = זה שקנה חכמה - One who has acquired wisdom. I don't know the origin of this idea.

Comment: Can you elaborate regarding the scholarly stature threshold for requiring people to get up? Or is standing simply the expression of great respect, in which case it's up to you and your appraisal of the man?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I would also be very interested to know the answer to @einpoklum's question--what is the threshold that defines whether we stand? Also--if we don't know how much of a scholar someone is, should we stand for him or not? Also, do women also stand, or only men?

Comment: @SAH It's gender independent for both the stand-er and the stand-ee.

Comment: @einpoklum [Pseudo](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14738/759)-Rama there comments that so long as the scholar is more scholarly than you that he could be your teacher, you should stand. The Shakh there comments that this must mean significantly more scholarly than most people AND more scholarly than you. (I agree these categories are not so precise.)

Comment: @DoubleAA: If that were the case, most people would just have to stand up for every Talmid 7achaam. Which (to my very limited knowledge) is never the case. My guess would be significantly more scholarly than *most scholars* and *significantly* more scholarly than you. Perhaps you even need to be some sort of a scholar yourself to even respect this custom, i.e. lay men are exempt.

Comment: @einpoklum This is not a custom. This is a biblical commandment which all adult Jews are obligated in. It's one of the 613 commandments (#257 in the Chinukh).

Comment: @DoubleAA: Right you are.

Comment: @DanF - the idea is brought by Rashi in the Gemoro in Kiddushin that DoubleAA mentions - https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.32b.8?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Kiddushin.32b.8.4&lang2=bi